# Is Select optional in a LINQ statement?

Tags: linq, select, ienumerable

I was looking over some LINQ examples, and was thereby reminded they are supposed to have a "select" clause at the end.

But I have a LINQ that's working and has no "Select":

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> Get(string ID, int packSize, int CountToFetch)
{
    return inventoryItems
        .Where(i => (i.Id.CompareTo(ID) == 0 && i.PackSize > packSize) || i.Id.CompareTo(ID) > 0)
        .OrderBy(i => i.Id)
        .ThenBy(i => i.PackSize)
        .Take(CountToFetch)
        .ToList();
}
```

Is this because:

```
(a) select is not really necessary?
(b) Take() is doing the "select"
(c) ToList() is doing the "select"
```

Truth be told, this was working before I added the "ToList()" also... so it seems LINQ is quite permissive/lax in what it allows one to get away with.

Also, in the LINQ I'm using, I think the OrderBy and ThenBy are redundant, because the SQL query used to populate inventoryItems already has an ORDER BY ID, PackSize clause. Am I right (that the .OrderBy() and .ThenBy() are unnecessary)?

Comment: Side-note: in VB.NET the `Select` is always optional, in cases of doubt an `IEnumerable(Of anonymous type)` with multiple properties is created automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linq statements do in fact need a `select` clause (or other clauses, such as a `group by`). However, you're not using Linq syntax, you're using the Linq `Enumerable` extension methods, which all (for the most part) return `IEnumerable<T>`. Therefore, they do not need the `Select` operator.

```
var result = from item in source
             where item.Value > 5
             select item;
```

Is exactly the same as

```
var result = source.Where(item => item.Value > 5);
```

And for completeness:

```
var result = from item in source
             where item.Value > 5
             select item.Value;
```

Is exactly the same as

```
var result = source.Where(item => item.Value > 5)
                   .Select(item => item.Value);
```

Linq statements (Linq syntax statements) need a special clause at the end to signify what the result of the query should be. Without a `select`, `group by`, or other selection clause, the syntax is incomplete, and the compiler does not know how to change the expression into the appropriate extension methods (which is what Linq syntax actually gets compiled to).

As far as `ToList` goes, that's one of the `Enumerable` extension methods that *does not* return an `IEnumerable<t>`, but instead a `List<T>`. When you use `ToList` or `ToArray` the `Enumerable` is enumerated immediately and converted to a list or array. This is useful if your query is complex and you need to enumerate the results multiple times without running the query multiple times).

Comment: Ah, so I think I get it now: the inverted (select-at-the-end) sql-like statements need the select, but the "fluent" syntax (like I'm using) does not.

Comment: Tim, the point is to note that you do *not* need a select statement... we are not trying to show a case where a select operator needs to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You only use select when you want to project your object into a different type..

if you had a list that contains an object with an ID property that was an int

```
var newList = items.Select(i => i.ID);
```

newList would be an `IEnumerable<int>`

---

NB.

A common mistake is to mix up a `Select` with a `Where`.

`items.Where(i => i.ID == 1);` returns an `IEnumerable<item>`

`items.Select(i => i.ID == 1);` returns an `IEnumerable<bool>`

as the Select projects each item into the result of the function passed in..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris Maybe I didn't make my answer clear enough. What I meant to say was..  You **only** need to use select when you want a different type from the type in your IEnumerable.